# Average difference between values SQL

Tags: sql, average, difference

I'm trying to find the difference between values using SQL where the second value is always larger than the previous value.

Example Data:

```
Car_ID | Trip_ID | Mileage
1       1         10,000
1       2         11,000
1       3         11,500
2       1         5,000
2       2         7,000
2       3         8,000
```

Expect Calculation:

```
Car_ID: 1
(Trip 2 - Trip 1) = 1,000 
(Trip 3 - Trip 2) = 500
Average Difference: 750

Car_ID: 2
(Trip 2 - Trip 1) = 2,000 
(Trip 3 - Trip 2) = 1,000
Average Difference: 1,500
```

Expected Output:

```
Car_ID | Average_Difference
1        750 
2        1,500
```

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: Does the mileage increases with each trip (ie does trip4>trip3>trip2 > trip1)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use aggregation:

```
select car_id,
       (max(mileage) - min(mileage)) / nullif(count(*) - 1, 0)
from t
group by car_id;
```

That is, the average as you have defined it is the maximum minus the minimum divided by one less than the number of trips.

Comment: why the nullif? doenst count(*) always give non-null values

Comment: @GeorgeJoseph . . . Yes, but if the value is `1`, then the division will fail.  Actually, `nullif()` does the *opposite* of what you are thinking.  It returns `NULL` when the expression's value is `0`.